# Pagination is not working on custom query

Tags: customization, pagination

I have `custom query` with different conditions so that's why my `pagination` is not working with it. When i click on next button it show me the same posts. The `query` i am using are

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;?>

if($selectedoption){
                        $args = array(
                            'posts_per_page' => 30,
                            'paged' => $paged, 
                            'post_type' => 'post', 
                            'include' => $catID02,
                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                            'meta_query' => array(  array(
                                    'key' => $checkkey,
                                    'value' => $checktoption
                                                )
                                                        ),
                            'author'=> $user_id  
                            );
                    }

                else if($tag_filter){
                    $args = array(
                    'posts_per_page' => 30,
                    'paged' => $paged, 
                    'post_type' => 'post', 
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'meta_query' => array(  array(
                            'key' => 'post_state',
                            'value' => $tag_filter
                                        )
                                                ),
                    'author'=> $user_id  
                    );
                }
else{
 $args = array('posts_per_page' => 10, 'paged' => $paged, 'post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish' ); 
                    } ?>


<?php query_posts($args); ?> 


<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

//content here

```
<?php endwhile; ?>
                <div class="span10 pagination">
                    <?php next_posts_link(); ?>
                    <?php previous_posts_link(); ?>
                    <?php //if(function_exists('wp_simple_pagination')) {
                        //wp_simple_pagination(); } ?> 
                </div>
                <!-- pagination -->

                <?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So what can i do in order to make pagination working. Thanks

Comment: try to add `global $post;` before `if ( have_posts() )...`

Comment: its still not working.